# Data missing in BigQuery from Firebase Analytics for the period January to March this year

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I have successfully connected BigQuery to Firebase Analytics, but I noticed that there is a data gap in BigQuery for the period from January to March this year, even though the data exists in Firebase. I want to supplement this missing data in BigQuery. Could you please guide me on how to achieve this?

[image: Data missing in BigQuery]

[image: Data exists in Firebase]

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you export it via GA4? Instead of using BQ filter, just write a simple select query to filter by dates.